# JButton not appearing on JPanel despite using correct layout managers, etc

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jbutton

I have been working with Swing for a while now on my CS project and, this may sound redundant, but I am unable to pop in my JButton in my JPanel. There are two other buttons which follow the same code and they get displayed but this one I create just refuses to show up. The button is "View Question" button. Similar buttons like the OK and CANCEL work fine. Any help would be much appreciated. The code:

```
public class CatNodePicker {

private final JDialog dialog;
private String selectedNodeCode;
private XMLTreeNode selectedNode;
private JTree cat;

public CatNodePicker(Container container, JTree cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
    selectedNodeCode = null;
    selectedNode = null;
    dialog =new JDialog(findParentFrame(container), "Pick a LEAF node", true);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    final JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.setEnabled(false);
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });
    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            selectedNodeCode = null;
            selectedNode = null;
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });

    JButton viewQuestion = new JButton("View Question");
    viewQuestion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            getQuestionLabel();
        }
    });

    buttonPanel.add(okButton);
    buttonPanel.add(viewQuestion);
    buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);

    cat.expandRow(1);
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(cat);

    cat.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            TreePath path=e.getNewLeadSelectionPath();
            if(path==null) {
                selectedNodeCode = null;
                selectedNode = null;
            }

            if (path.getLastPathComponent().equals(path.getPathComponent(1))) {
                selectedNodeCode = null;
                selectedNode = null;
            }
            else {
                XMLTreeNode n=((XMLTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent());
                //System.out.println(n.toString());
                if(n.isLeaf() || n.isFilter() || n.isLayer()) {
                    selectedNodeCode = n.getCode();
                    selectedNode = n;
                    okButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else
                    okButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    });

    dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            selectedNodeCode = null;
            selectedNode = null;
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });  

    dialog.getContentPane().add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dialog.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(600,800));
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.pack();

}

public JComponent getQuestionLabel(){

    JLabel questionText= new JLabel("Question here");
    return questionText;

}
```

}

In short, I want a "View Question" button in between the OK and CANCEL buttons. Please help. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Your "View Question" button ***is*** between the OK and Cancel buttons!

Comment: did you try setting an explicit layout manager on the panel that contains your buttons?  I know it's supposed to default to FlowLayout, and that LOOKS like it would be ok, but I don't trust Swing defaults all the time...

Comment: I have no issue with getting the code to work (when I remove the stuff you didn't include)

Comment: Ditto on what @MadProgrammer says. A problem I see is that you're trying to set the dialog's size -- don't do that. That's the layout manager's job. Just pack and go.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, what is the code you didn't include from here? Could you give me a sample of it or something? Do I need to add/subtract anything in this?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, the dialog's size is large enough the encapsulate these three buttons... Do you still think that I must remove it?

Comment: @rcook, I did try setting the layout to FLow Layout, but it didn't help. Can you please give me sample code or something?

Comment: I don't think it will help. There are any number of examples of adding buttons to containers under flowlayout on the web; since those work and yours doesn't, there is something different (and likely incorrect) about yours. We need more complete code; I suggest you remove this dialog creation from your app, invoke it from a small testing program that does nothing but invoke it, and we'll debug from there. If you can't figure it out from that, you can post the whole thing, and then we can all see what's happening.

Comment: @SharadhaJayaraman I had to take out the reference to the XMLTreeNode and all the ActionListeners. As to HoverCraftFullOfEels comment about the dialog size - it looks fond on YOUR system, but we don't all use the same font or font size ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this though I don't expect it to help very much.  It illustrates that what you are doing works in the simple case, and that to answer your question we need to figure out where you deviate from the simple case (and from correct Swing usage).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Dialoger
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dialoger dialoger = new Dialoger();
        dialoger.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        JDialog jd = new JDialog();
        JButton one = new JButton("one");
        JButton two = new JButton("two");
        JButton three = new JButton("three");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(three);
        jd.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jd.pack();
        jd.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked fine :) Some problem with running the wrong class. Thank you everyone ^_^